# What was the population of the main area of settlement in New York City in 1890?

Tags: population, new-york

Many population figures given for the population of cities may include the surrounding rural areas and villages. The available number I have found for New York of 1890 includes the entirety of today's Manhattan and Bronx. I would like to know what the population of only the central/old/main city was? as there was much rural area (and probably also other centers of settlement in north Manhattan or in the Bronx) included in this area.

The source of this question is as follows:
In Jewish law, one of the standards to define a "Large Public City" is 600,000 residents. (It's actually a bit more complicated than this simple definition, but the place for dealing with that is on Mi Yodeya).
We were studying some Jewish texts written about at the turn of the century which list some of the cities that were/may have been considered "Large Public City" at that time.

Comment: The rural areas kind of by definition aren't going to be contributing too horribly much to that total though, right?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Does [demographia.com](http://demographia.com/db-nyuza1800.htm) help?  That suggests the population was 2,693,000.  Alternatively there  seems to have been a [NYC Police Census](https://www.nypl.org/blog/2019/05/09/1890-new-york-city-police-census) in 1890

Comment: This seems to be an X-Y question to me. Please explain Why you want this number, which seems to be *a priori* uninteresting precisely because NYC apparently didn't care what it was. There also serious questions about the accuracy of any census at the time, due to widespread Tammany hall corruption.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the problem you are going to run into here is that the detailed records for the [1890 US Census were damaged in a fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1890_United_States_census), then (purposely!) destroyed by the US government.

However, you are in a bit of luck here, because NYC was suspicious it was getting cheated out of congressional representation by the 1890 census, so they [commissioned their own](https://www.nypl.org/blog/2019/05/09/1890-new-york-city-police-census). However, given the motivations (proving the official census was low) there are legitimate concerns that the extra 200,000 residents it discovered were made up.

If you are willing to live with that, it should be possible to take the data and exclude whatever areas you desire.

Unfortunately, even the NYC Police Census [supposedly isn't easily available online](https://libguides.nypl.org/nycpolicecensus), and some of its records were lost too. I can vouch that I'm having trouble finding online resources at the granularity you need. It seems like most folks interested in the data want to know about individual addresses for genealogical purposes.

My best guess is that if you were to go through all the trouble to look it up offline, and to weed out the more rural areas, you'd likely come out with roughly the official US figure for NYC's population (the rural population being roughly balanced by the extra count NYC's Census made). Either way, the *actual* size of the city in 1890 is in dispute by about 200,000, which is likely going to swamp any extra precision you'd get by excluding rural areas.

Comment: I would recommend the 1892 NY State Census, which is readily available at multiple genealogy sites.

Comment: @shoover - The NYC "Police Census" is available on genealogy sites too. However, as I mentioned, I found the tools provided to access it geared toward looking up personal data for individual addresses, not toward getting topline numbers for areas. I'm kind of suspicious that this wouldn't also be a problem for these same sites' presentation of the 1892 data.